# How is it that my random operator is being printed by using an unassigned variable?

Tags: c++

Letting you know, the code works, I have a different problem that I think is unique but not sure. This is a simple addition or subtraction math problem program. My problem here is that I have an if statement saying if my variable is 1 then print "+" otherwise print "-". So when variable op is 1 or not 1 it will give me my operator sign. However, I placed string T for where I wanted the operator to print and it so happens to print my operator and I have no idea why. Is that ok? Please let me know thanks! hopefully its something easy. I just started out in C++, but i love it so much more than python already :)!!!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
int main() { 

     // establishing variables 
     using namespace std; 

     srand(time(0));
     int op= rand()%2;
     int x= rand() % 300; 
     int y= rand() % 300;
     int I;
     int sum;
     string T;

     cout << "Solve this problem. \n" << endl;

     cout << setw(3) << x << endl;

     if(op ==1)
    { 
        sum = x + y;
        cout<< "+";
    }

     else
    {
        cout << "-";
        sum = x - y;
    }

     cout<< T << endl;

     cout << setw(3) << y << "\n" << endl;

     cin >> I;

     ;

     if (I == sum)
        cout<< "That is correct!";

     else
        cout<< "That is wrong :( \n The correct answer is " << sum << endl;


     system("pause");
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't assigning anything into T, it is an empty string.
It is printing the operator since you are printing it inside the if/else scope.

Comment: oh so you are saying cout << t << endl; is blank basically and the result of the if statment prints out my operator?

Comment: not the result, the side effect but basically yes.

Comment: sweet that was easy god i have no common sense sometimes lol